# I can,t copy text from my website

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem. I can't copy text from my wordpress website anymore. can someone tell me how to enable it again. I don't know why that happened.

Comment: This is the website. [link](https://dudetheme.com/about)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following in your CSS (i.e. https://www.dudetheme.com/wp-content/themes/dudetheme/style.css):

```
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:-moz-none;
-ms-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
```

to

```
-webkit-user-select:all;
-moz-user-select:all;
-ms-user-select:all;
user-select:all;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you installed a plugin. Please disable the recently added plugin. And if you don't remember which plugin you used recently, then try to disable all the plugins one by one and check.